# How to traffic data between Google Cloud SQL and Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-sql

Cloud SQL documentation about [connecting with external apps](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) didn't helped me much. Isn't there some library to handle data traffic like Firebase's Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database offer?

Comment: "handle" and "traffic data" does mean what exactly here?

Comment: Creating, reading, updating and deleting data. Sorry for misunderstood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use cloud functions to provide an API for Flutter and access to the DB
or run your custom server in the Google cloud that does that.

SQL databases should never be accessed over the internet directly and instead hidden behind a web server that only exposes a limited or specialized API.